# Static wcf client to make multiple request with one object

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I want to make a static client to call a wcf because the first time I call the wcf it takes too long, even sometimes it throws time out.

I have the following class:

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    protected static ServiceClient Client { get; set; }

    public Repository()
    {
        if (Client == null)
        {
            Client = new ServiceClient();
        }

        if (Client.ChannelFactory.State != CommunicationState.Opened 
            || Client.ChannelFactory.State != CommunicationState.Created)
        {
            Client = new ServiceClient();
        }
    }

    public virtual async Task<Response> GetPersonsFromAddress(string address)
    {
        try
        {
            Request request = new Request();
            request.Address = address;
            Response response = await Client.GetPersonsAsync(request);

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // ...
            // Handle exception
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

And this class calls the method:

```
public class Conector : IConector
{
    private IRepository Repository { get; }

    public Conector()
    {
        Repository = new Repository();
    }

    public virtual async Task<Response> GetPersonsFromAddress(string address)
    {
        Response response = await Repository.GetPersonsFromAddress(address);
        return response;
    }
}
```

The object that calls the wcf service is static so I want to know if this is a good practice.

Also if there are a lot of people at the same time using this method, it will return the correct response for each request.

Comment: Is the variable Cliente and Client meant to be the same?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Yes! Sorry for that, now it is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should consider [inverting control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) and moving `ServiceClient` instantiation outside the repository class. Whether or not `ServiceClient` is a singleton (in single-instance sense) or not is not something that repository should manage or care about:

```
public class Conector : IConector
{
    private IRepository Repository { get; }

    public Conector(IRepository repository)
    {
         Repository = repository;
    }
    ...
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    protected ServiceClient Client { get; }

    public Repository(ServiceClient client)
    {
        Client = client;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Is it ok to have 2 constructors? One for the dependency injection and the other one for a default inialization of the inyected class? Like `public Conector()` in the question and `public Conector(IRepository repository)` like yours?

Comment: @Sxntk it depends on what default constructor would actually do. If it is going to create and manage some static instance of `ServiceClient`class then it is hardly an improvement. You would just move the problem from one class to another.